# Rules for running new electric outlets

Tags: receptacle, conduit

I'm looking at buying my first house and since everyone finishes the inside of the garage with sheetrock I will need to run some new lines or my car charger, milling machine, table saw, etc no matter what house I end up getting, because if there are any 240v outlets it's prob only 1 but usually there are none at all the places I've looked at so far.

I know wire size and breakers already and I know wire has to be inside a conduit. What I'm not sure on is can I use Smurf tube to run lines or is that only for inside the walls. I don't wanna have to buy a crapload of hard conduit for running if I can get away with something cheaper.

I won't know till I buy a house obviously but I know that I can run the lines inside the walls after the fact but some of the places I've looked at will have no crawl space above the garage due to the 2nd floor and it's just easier of I get a place like that so I can be prepared to wire in anything no matter what place I get.

Comment: Where are you located? The rules for this can vary significantly based on the jurisdiction.  Using metal clad cables is going to be the easiest way to avoid conduit, and opening up walls. But it’s not legal everywhere or in all situations.

Comment: @GrassMan Nevada is where I'm gonna buy a home. I totally didn't even think of that armored wire, that's an interesting idea.

Comment: smurf tube is low-voltage only I think. NM cable would normally not be inside any conduit. You should take a look at one of those homeowner-targeted "Wiring" books at a big box store or your library to get an idea of typical wiring/conduit options.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify the exact question, probably including the type of circuit, type of structure it will go through, and any other considerations like price?

Comment: *my EV i have to hard wire it because it needs its own dedicated 100A circuit so I can charge at 80A* that's a crazy amount of power, basically half a standard 200A feed just for EV. How many miles do you drive a day? 20A will typically charge 100 miles a night. 80A??? Do you plan on driving 2 EVs 150 or more miles each every day?

Comment: @Armand -- ENT aka "smurf tube" is legal for 120V wiring, but not where you have potential exposure to mechanical damage.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'm aware 100 is half of 200 lol. Do I need to charge at 80A? not really. Do I like the option to be able to do so? Hell yeah. Convince is the name of the game which is why I have a Gen2 HPWC brand new in the box sitting aside since they don't make them anymore. And it's the only brand and model that can do 80A and it was only $400

Answer (score 1):

A garage is an excellent place to practice the new skill of drywall repair.

Cut whatever access you need (from inside the garage) to run the circuits you need/want to run, run them, and repair the access holes in the drywall. No stress about the finish being perfect, because it's a garage. And that way you can use ENT, because it's protected in the wall.

Comment: Can I use ENT for 240v? someone said in a comment earlier that it was only for 120v runs and I am only planning to run 240v outlets

Comment: It's fine for 240V, which is 120V to ground, twice. In fact, according to https://www.cantexinc.com/resources/faq#148924-is-there-a-voltage-limit-for-ent   *"Is there a voltage limit for ENT?
Yes, all ENT is restricted to **600** Volts or less."* emphasis added by me.